# installation error media is either dirty or damaged

Tags: installation, 12.10

There is an installation error which states that there is an issue with the installation media(in this case a cd-rom).

[image]

[image]

thanks for your time.. Installing on a Sony VAIO machine

any recommendations??

Comment: Are you able to login to Ubuntu?

Comment: Try to do exactly how is written in those informations about the error.

Comment: >>are you able to log in to Ubuntu? -- No I just get past the creation of the login when I get this error....... ..Try to do exactly how is written in those informations about the error. -- I am using a USB, the directions refer to CD/DVD instal. As far as the hard disk is OK I was using it fine for months.. something I am missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the usb to install ubuntu instead of a cd-rom. Save the .iso file to from the ubuntu.com/downloads

Then download linux live from http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download and run it.

While running the program,insert the usb drive you want to boot ubuntu from and select the .iso file and the program burns it to your usb drive.

Boot your laptop from external device(1st priority) and install ubuntu.

Comment: thank you, saket, for your response.. it has helped me greatly